# How to import angular HttpModule to the root NgModule

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am beginning with ionic v2, angular2 and typeScript. So i am trying to set up an ionic login page which retrieves login credentials and contact the remote api for authentication. I obviously need angular Http Client.

The **src/app/app.component.ts** looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';


import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = LoginPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

**src/app/app.module.ts** looks like:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { AuthService } from '../providers/auth-service';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,

  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},AuthService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Of course any other necessary files (page/login/login.* and provider/auth-service.ts) are defined, so there is no missing file or service error.

THE PROBLEM:

When i build the app via `ionic serve`, the process finishes without errors, but when launching the app in the browser, i get this error:

**Unexpected module "HttpModule" declared by the module "AppModule"**
Nevertheless i am just following instructions from [this tutorial from the official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html).
I have been googling since a couple of hours without finding a workaround.
Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Move `HttpModule` to `imports` array. And also `JsonpModule` Read more https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-what-to-import

Comment: @yurzui, thanks, and sorry for the stupid question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should import **`HttpModule`** as follow,

```
imports: [   
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule
    ...
    ...
}
```

**NOTE:** Same with **`JsonpModule`**. And don't forget to remove them from **`declarations`** array.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the sooo stupid question, but i have to mark an answer as true, and it is yours.

Comment: happens !! its okay !!

Comment: one comment from my side. While importing the HttpModule VsCode imports it with wrong package like `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http/src/http_module';`. one should fix the package too `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';` so that it can work.

Answer (score 1):

`declarations` property is used to declare every components and pipes you have in this module, allowing you to use them in the module.

To use another module in the current one, you have to use `imports` property, like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},AuthService]
})
```

Comment: Technically your answer is not true, because you have forgotten to move the 'JsonpModule' too... i am therefore obliged to mark @micronyks as true.

Comment: woops yes indeed, he edited his answer while I did not because I didn't see this :/ EDIT: edited it but whatever, if you got what you were looking for everything is fine :D

Comment: I saw your answer and I didn't know about that, learnt something today thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as Ionic 2 is concerned, you need not separately import **HttpModule** at all. [**IonicModule**](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/index.ts#L307) does that for you like so in the link:

```
exports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
```

You can directly use the components.Similar for forms.